# Non Negative Linear Least Squares with Order Constraint

Tags: optimization, manifolds, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, least-squares

I have a very familiar problem, **non-negative least squares** (NNLS), with the added constraint that the first element in the solution vector is larger than the second, which is larger than the third, and so on. That is, given $A$ and $d$,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \|Ax - d\|_2\\ \text{subject to} & x_1 \geq x_2 \geq \cdots \geq x_n\\ & x_i \geq 0\end{array}$$

Can you think of any way to tweak the [active set method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares#Algorithms) for normal NNLS such that the ordering constraint is also satisfied? Presumably a result $x'$ provided by the normal NNLS sits on a manifold of other NNLS solutions, which can be traversed until the order constraint is satisfied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple transformation allows you to apply any standard method to this. Just consider nonnegative variables $y_i$, $i=1,2,\dots, n$, and define
$$x_n = y_n, \quad x_{n-1} = x_n + y_{n-1}, \quad \dots \quad x_1 = x_2 + y_1$$
Or, equivalently,
$$x_k = \sum_{i=k}^n y_k \quad \Longrightarrow \quad x = E y$$
where $E$ is the upper triangular matrix of all ones.
Now we have
$$\|Ax-d\|_2 = \|AEy-d\|_2$$
giving you a standard NNLS problem to work with.

I'm sure you can tweak an existing active-state method to consider the monotonicity constraint directly---instead of partitioning $y$ into zero and non-zero values, you partition $x$ in to elements that are equal to the next, and strictly greater than. But it might be better to just use existing machinery on the transformed problem.

One downside is that forming $AE$ would destroy sparsity. But $E$ does have a nice $O(n)$ structure, so algorithms that can exploit more general structure than sparsity will work well with $AE$.

Comment: On one hand I'm happy that the answer is so simple but on the other hand im mad that I didn't think of it. Much obliged.

Comment: Very Nice! +1. Those tricks are so great.